# My DropDownListFor does not select the SelectedValue from my SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

My DropDownListFor does not select the SelectedValue from my SelectList, it always selected the first item instead. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Showing pictures of code when you could just copy and paste it as text makes me sad.  This question has less of a chance of helping other developers, unless Google performs OCR on your image :) Also very difficult to read on a phone...

Comment: sorry for making you sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, actually, on second thought, double check sublegerType_Id? I'm not sure it should be the Id. I think it needs to be the actual object.

for example, this doesnt work (it defaults to the first item)

```
        List<Tuple<string, string>> NumberList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            NumberList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(i.ToString(),i.ToString()));
        }
        NumberSelectList = new SelectList(NumberList,"2");
```

but this works okay (it defaults to the selected item of (4,4))

```
        List<Tuple<string, string>> NumberList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        Tuple<string, string> selectedObject = new Tuple<string, string>("-1","-1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4)
            {
                selectedObject = new Tuple<string, string>(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                NumberList.Add(selectedObject);
            }
            else
                NumberList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));


        }
        NumberSelectList = new SelectList(NumberList, selectedObject);
```

Comment: Do you mean the SelectedValue in the SelectList is ignored?

Comment: I tried binding the object itself as the selected item, but does not work for me. My guess is that the drop down is binding to an int type, but the selectedlist is content object type, that is why the view couldn't bind the Id as the selected value <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubLedgerType_Id, new SelectList(Model.GetActiveSubLedgerType(), "Id", "Code", Model.SubLedgerType_Id))%>

Comment: My mistake, I am binding to the wrong id. Your solution work perfectly