# DropDownListFor() does not select required item on get request (on post request works)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've dusted off an older project (MVC 5.2.2) and discovered that one of my *DropDownListFor()* usages does not work correctly if the page is rendered first time as response on *HttpGet* request: generated HTML code does not contain selected attribute at all.

If I inspect view model i.e. *SelectList* items (in the controller and int the rendered view), the required item has member *Selected* set to true. Item's *Id* is **enum** value.

When the same page is rendered as response to *HttpPost* request, everything works OK. The worst is, when inspecting model, the values are the same as on *HttpGet* request and *SelectLists* are in both cases created the same routine...

Instead using **enum** as selected item *Id* I tried an instance of complete item for selected one as in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952373/my-dropdownlistfor-does-not-select-the-selectedvalue-from-my-selectlist) with the same result: does not work on *HttpGet*.

The list is constructed this way:

```
  List<CashType> types;
  if (AIncludeAll)
    types = ADbContext.CashTypes.OrderBy(c => c.Ident).ToList();
  else
    types = ADbContext.CashTypes.Where(c => c.Id != CashTypeValues.All).OrderBy(c => c.Ident).ToList();
  //
  foreach (var type in types)
    type.Translation = CashTypeValueToDescription(type.Id);
  return new SelectList(types, "Id", "Translation", ACashType);
```

CashType comes from DB model:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public CashTypeValues Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(DBDomains.D_IDENTCODE)]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string Ident { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Translation { get; set; }
```

view model is

```
[Display(Name = "View_Unit_CashType", ResourceType = typeof(WebGui))]
public CashTypeValues CashType { get; set; }
public SelectList CashTypes { get; set; }
```

finally, usage in Razor looks like this:

```
<div class="Theme-Bottom-Filter-Field">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CashType)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CashType, Model.CashTypes, new { Id = "CashTypeSelector" })
</div>
```

Does anybody has an idea what I'm missing?

Thanx, pf

Comment: in my experience selected in the list is ignored.  make sure that the value of CashType equals what you want selected

Comment: The CashType value uis equal with item.Id I wont to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `Selected` is true on the `SelectListItem` is inconsequential. When Razor renders the drop down list, it sets the selected value based on `ModelState`, so if the proper value is not being selected that means the proper value does not exist in `ModelState`.

`ModelState` is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag` and finally `Model`. Generally, you'll just want to ensure that the model you're passing to the view has the appropriate value set. If you want the property on your view model to have a default value, for example, you can do:

```
private CashTypeValues? cashType;
public CashTypeValues CashType
{
    get { return cashType ?? CashTypeValues.Default; }
    set { cashType = value; }
}
```

Or, in C# 6+:

```
public CashTypeValues CashType { get; set; } = CashTypeValues.Default;
```

However, since values in `Request` and `ViewData`/`ViewBag` actually take precedence, you need to ensure that you're not passing an incorrect value that way. For example, if you had a query string like `?cashType=foo`, then the selected value would be "foo", rather than whatever you had on your model originally. You also should avoid setting something like `ViewBag.CashType`. It's also important to note that in all of these cases, naming is case-insensitive. When it comes to `ModelState`, foo == FOO == Foo == fOO.

Comment: You are right: query string with the same name as part of HttpGet URL is the evil. I had to pass default values to parent model/view and include them into query string to avoid this strange behaviour: why the hell the renderer does not simply render the responded model and takes care about input values which should not be its business :-( Anyway, thanks for prompt usefull answer.